# Looking to make an irrigation system (no faucet) for my balcony plants

Tags: watering

My balcony is about 10 X 5 ft in size. I travel every year for about 4 months. Every time I return my balcony greenery is dead and the few surviving plants border line dead.  Friends or neighbors I ask to check on my plants obviously do not although they claim they did.About to leave in December so I am looking to make a system using a barrel, a submersible water pump, water pump connected to power outlet with perhaps the use of a timer or some device that could start watering perhaps twice a week or by use of humidity sensors. The barrel could be replenished with water every two weeks ... one of my neighbors could do that ... easier than asking to care for plants ... and that would be a good system but I do not know what to get .  Need advise . Plants are living beings and I hate to leave only to return and see all dead . What pump to get.  What timer or else humidity sensors, please advise . No water tap in the balcony (why would  builders make balconies without water taps ... hard to imagine !

Comment: Hi Jamie, this site works best with one question per post. Its also difficult to expect one prrson to answer all the bits. You can find cheap submersible pumps for water features on ebay.  Even solar powered one. Start from there.

Comment: I think this may be closed as off-topic shopping advice, but in general I see the type of thing you're looking for described as "Timer water pump" or "timer irrigation pump".  Alternatively https://www.instructables.com/ can be great for DIY-ish information like this.